# Test input element click invocation when label is clicked

Tags: reactjs, onclick, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test a scenario where an input component (radio/ checkbox) click event is invoked when the label is clicked. Following is my code,

**Toggle.jsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies
import styled from 'styled-components'; // eslint-disable-line import/no-extraneous-dependencies

import Label from '../Label/Label';

const ToggleButtonController = styled.button`
  background-color: red;
`;

const ToggleInputController = styled.input`
  background-color: red;
`;

const Toggle = (props) => {
  const { label } = props;

  let toggleControllerRef = null;

  const renderLabel = () => {
    return (
      <Label
        onClick={() => { toggleControllerRef.click(); }} // <--- untested line where I invoke the input element click event on label click
      >
        { label }
      </Label>
    );
  };


  const renderController = () => {
    const { labelPosition, disabled, type, onClick, onChange } = props;

    let controller = (
      <div>
        <ToggleInputController
          onClick={onClick}
          onChange={onChange}
          innerRef={(toggleController) => { toggleControllerRef = toggleController; }}
          type={type === 'switch' ? 'checkbox' : type}
          disabled={disabled}
        />
      </div>
    );

    if (type === 'button') {
      controller = (
        <div>
          <ToggleButtonController
            onClick={onClick}
            disabled={disabled}
            {...commonUtils.filterProps(Toggle.propTypes, props)}
          >
            { label }
          </ToggleButtonController>{ renderRequired() }
        </div>
      );
    }

    return controller;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {
        renderController()
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Toggle;
```

**toggle.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { Toggle } from '../src/index';

describe('Test Toggle component', () => {
  it('Test checkbox element label click event', () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();
    const toggle = shallow(<Toggle type="checkbox" onClick={mockCallBack} label="test" />);

    toggle.find('Label').last().get(0).click; // i want to trigger onClick in the above Toggle when the label is clicked

    expect(mockCallBack).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }); 
});
```

With this code snippet, the test fails stating the mockCallBack was not called.

This is the first time im testing UI elements and would appreciate a point in the right direction to achieve this requirement.

Thanks

Comment: should it be `toggle.find('Label').last().get(0).click()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of details you should consider to write this test.

### Simulating events

In order to simulate events, Enzyme wrappers provide the [`.simulate`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.md) method:

```
wrapper.find('a').simulate('click');
```

### Simulating events with shallow rendering

**Simulated events** with **shallow rendering**, **don't propagate as expected**. Therefore there are at least 2 options:

- Keep using **shallow render** and call `.simulate` directly on the element bound to the event callback
- Switch to Enzyme's [**full rendering**](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md) to take advantage on proper events propagation

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.. Yes i am aware of the simulate method. But in my senario, I attached a code snippet on lable click to invoke the onClick event on the toggle on label click. This doesnt seem to fire/ propegate as expected when i run the onlick on the label